# Angular ui-router current state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a resolve function in my program used to handle loginRequired. When I try to get the current state in the resolve function, it only gives me the '/login' state. Kindly help identify why.

```js
angular.module('mayday')
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
    controller: 'Ep',
    resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
    }
})

function loginRequired($q, $location, $auth, $state) {
    console.log($state);
    
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    else
    {
        $location.path('/auth/login');
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you're trying accessing `index.html` from `login`, if I'm not mistaken, this happen because `resolve` executes before load...so, before reaching `/home` it's still in `/login` on `resolve`. What do you want to achieve using `$state`?

Comment: Ok it makes sense it's in `/login` on resolve. I'm trying to get the intended `$state` during the resolve  i.e. `/home`

Comment: I've never worked with `ui-router` and I don't know all properties...but as `ngRouter` has `$route.current` to access the current route on `resolve`  doesn't `ui-router` has a `$state.current` or something like this?

Comment: In any case, I found this workaround. I think this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985988/angular-ui-router-get-state-info-of-tostate-in-resolve

Comment: Yes it does. but it is only given me the current as `/login` since it is actually in `/login` on resolve.  There's a workaround I'm trying to improve by using this approach. I could just use the ui-router `stateChangeEvents` to capture this movement.

Comment: I found that post. didn't work for me.

Comment: Hope you can manage to solve this with the workaround you've found. Sorry for not being able to help you more.

Comment: Yes I have. I just used `$location.path()`. Thank you Elmer.